# Why the values are not binded to the particular div class in html using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `card` Where, I couldn't bind the Value of the Particular Div Class `Completed` and `Non-completed` with the Values from their attributes using `innerHTML`.

Here is my codepen, https://codepen.io/DarKV/pen/jOwqMWo.

On clicking the `content2`, There were two div's with class `Completed and Not-completed` in a row. They both have the attribute `data-completed` and `data-notCompleted`. I need the Values from those attributes to be binded to the child div with the class `compValue` and `noncompValue`.

```
<div class="row row-paddingless">
  <div class="col mr-8">
    <div class="font-size-sm text-muted font-weight-bold completed" data-completed=600>Completed</div>
    <div class="font-size-h4 font-weight-bolder compValue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="font-size-sm text-muted font-weight-bold Not-completed" data-notCompleted=220>Yet to Complete</div>
    <div class="font-size-h4 font-weight-bolder noncompValue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, the values were not binded to the particular div. I need those Values to be used in the progress bar.

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: @Nikola Pavicevic, Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: You are missing quotes around `b1` in your `updateStates()` function.  Use this: `var cardId = document.getElementById("b1");`